# Methods that receive buffer objects AND return another Object - is that bad design?

Tags: java, design, code-quality

### The Argument

Some say that if you write a method that receives a buffer, iT MUST RETURN VOID -> the buffer is your exit point.
Do not abuse the methods by receiving buffers AND returning a another object.

```
Example (BAD):
Object myMethod(String param1, String param2, Map<K,V> bufferMap)

Example (Better):
void myMethod(String param1, String param2, Map<K,V> bufferMap, Object obj)
```

### The Counter Argument

Some say that this is fine and should not be a problem.

### The Question

- Is that a design problem ?
- (If yes) What issues\impacts could this kind of design have ?

#### EDIT

On the original question, I tried to keep it neutral to avoid any bias.
As pointed out by answers below, more context is needed since for some languages both implementations serve different purposes.

In my specific case, it is a on going discussion on a Java codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Like all "must", "always" or other imperial rules they're more guideline than hard rules.

First what is Object to buffer? Is it the difference between before and after the call to MyMethod? Is it an Error status? Why do you need it?

I think the rule to returning "void" and without adding a parameter so plainly is true if the buffer itself is the result:

```
void myMethod(String param1, String param2, Map<K,V> bufferMap)
```

Now if you really need more information I tend to prefer return value since they allow writing:

```
Object res = myMethod(String param1, String param2, Map<K,V> bufferMap);
```

Instead of:

```
Object res;
myMethod(String param1, String param2, Map<K,V> bufferMap, res);
```

A use case I see is for error handling:

```
enum potentialResults { Error, nothingToDo, OK }
potentialResults res = myMethod(String param1, String param2, Map<K,V> bufferMap);
switch (res) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I see your case, but should not error be exceptions instead ? Like a method will do something and produce a result to continue the code flow OR it throws an exception.

Comment: @linuxunil Not all languages have exceptions, in C I have seen a lot of error handling done like that because there are no exceptions.

Comment: @linuxunil Exceptions are *one* way to deal with errors. There are good reasons not to use them. Especially when you have ADTs available, but even without.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object myMethod(
    String param1, 
    String param2, 
    Map<K,V> bufferMap
)
```

Is not a problem if `bufferMap` is simply being “received”. It’s when it’s being changed by `myMethod` that things are getting confusing.

There is some wisdom behind this rule but it’s being masked with loose terms. Would a String count as a buffer? Why not?

I see the real issue as mixing return and out parameters. There isn’t a profound architectural reason. It’s about readability. Humans like to use one convention at a time. I don’t see anything special about a parameter being a buffer if you never change it. But if you do, while returning, then you’re expressing results in two different ways. That’s a bit confusing.

```
void myMethod(
    String param1, 
    String param2, 
    Map<K,V> bufferMap, 
    Object obj
)
```

When you’re mutating `bufferMap` that’s a bit less confusing. Since it returns void no ones going to confuse this with a side-effect-free pure function.

Comment: exactly. Imagine having a lot of such methods being called and mixing read\writes on parameters. It's exhausting to developers to check everything because you never know the behaviour.

Comment: @linuxunil I sometimes wish I worked in a language that had a pure function keyword that would signal and enforce function purity. Pure functions only make code easier to reason about when you can tell what they are.

Answer (score 0):

First, these two forms are not equivalent:

- returning some Object allows the callee to create or choose the object to return
- passing in an object requires the caller to create the Object in advance!

Second, these are fairly low level details whose merits go to the specifics of the language in use.  We need to understand if the language has:

- out parameters
- references
- multiple return values
- struct or record or tuples
- exceptions

Without these, it is low-level discussion but general across all languages, which is probably pointless!

Comment: Thanks for the input, I realized your points right after reading your answer. Edited the question.